# spring 3, hibernate, dbcp and derby connection issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, derby

I am using Spring 3, hibernate 3, derby 10.11 and apache DBCP2. I am using a dao(TestDao) to create the hibernate session factory. This DAO is auto-wired. 
I am getting the following exception when IOC is trying to instantiate the dao.

```
package com.springtest.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.springtest.entities.HotelAvailability;

@Repository
public class TestDao { 

@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public List<HotelAvailability> getHotels() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(HotelAvailability.class);
    List<HotelAvailability> hotels = (List<HotelAvailability>) criteria.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return hotels;
}
```

applicationcontext.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"   
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"       
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.springtest"/>

<bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/home/atanu/derby/testdb"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="2"/>
    <property name="maxTotal" value="5"/>
     <!-- <property name="username" value="atanu"/>
    <property name="password" value="passw0rd"/> -->
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan"  value="com.springtest.entities"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
 <aop:config>
     <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* com.springtest.di.Party.getType(..))" 
             id="mypointcut"/>
     <aop:aspect ref="myadvice">

         <!-- <aop:before method="before" pointcut-ref="mypointcut"/>
         <aop:after method="after" pointcut-ref="mypointcut"/> -->
         <aop:around method="watchPartyCreation" pointcut-ref="mypointcut" />

     </aop:aspect>
     <aop:aspect>
         <aop:declare-parents types-matching="com.springtest.di.Party+aopParent" 
             implement-interface="com.springtest.di.AopParent"
             default-impl="com.springtest.di.AopParentImpl"/>
     </aop:aspect>
 </aop:config>

</beans>
```

Exception:

```
    Sep 19, 2015 1:53:00 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1904b13: startup date [Sat Sep 19 13:53:00 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 19, 2015 1:53:00 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
Sep 19, 2015 1:53:00 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4336ff: defining beans [person,testDI,compositeBean,myadvice,organization,testDao,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,datasource,sessionFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,mypointcut,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.DeclareParentsAdvisor#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Sep 19, 2015 1:53:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate Annotations 3.3.0.GA
Sep 19, 2015 1:53:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 3.2 cr4
Sep 19, 2015 1:53:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
Sep 19, 2015 1:53:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: Bytecode provider name : cglib
Sep 19, 2015 1:53:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
Sep 19, 2015 1:53:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: com.springtest.entities.HotelAvailability
Sep 19, 2015 1:53:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder bindTable
INFO: Bind entity com.springtest.entities.HotelAvailability on table HOTELAVAILABILITY
Sep 19, 2015 1:53:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration secondPassCompile
INFO: Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
Sep 19, 2015 1:53:01 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean buildSessionFactory
INFO: Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
Sep 19, 2015 1:53:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration secondPassCompile
INFO: Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
Sep 19, 2015 1:53:01 PM org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory newConnectionProvider
INFO: Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider
Sep 19, 2015 1:53:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4336ff: defining beans [person,testDI,compositeBean,myadvice,organization,testDao,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,datasource,sessionFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,mypointcut,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.DeclareParentsAdvisor#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testDI': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.springtest.dao.TestDao com.springtest.di.TestDI.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.springtest.dao.TestDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.isValid(I)Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.springtest.di.TestDI.loadSpringContext(TestDI.java:21)
    at com.springtest.di.TestDI.main(TestDI.java:32)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.springtest.dao.TestDao com.springtest.di.TestDI.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.springtest.dao.TestDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.isValid(I)Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.springtest.dao.TestDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.isValid(I)Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.springtest.dao.TestDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.isValid(I)Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.isValid(I)Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.isValid(I)Z
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:918)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:357)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2307)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2290)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2039)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:1933)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:915)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:863)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:782)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 1):

DBCP seems to be configured to test the validity of the connections by calling `Connection.isValid()`, but the implementation of Connection provided by the JDBC driver you're using is based on an older version of the JDBC API which didn't have this method yet.

I guess that Derby must have a newer driver that supports this method (you're using old versions of Spring and Hibernate, so I guess you also have an old version of the driver).

If it doesn't, then I guess you should also be able to configure DBCP not to test the validity of connections, or to test it in another way.

If you're starting a new project, then please don't use Spring 3 and Hibernate 3. They're both very old. Upgrade to their latest version, and enjoy all the improvements and bug fixes that have been made in the last 5 years.

Comment: Apache Derby `10.11` is the last release (`10.11.1.1` in fact), and they are `JDBC 4.2` compatible as you can see [here](https://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.11.1.1.cgi#Overview). But the point with an older version is valid, maybe would be good to check if the dependency isn't managed to an older version due to transitive dependencies or such (in case you use maven).

Comment: In particular, there is often a copy of Derby bundled with your JDK, and if you aren't alert to that, it is common to get two different versions of Derby in your CLASSPATH. That, coupled with the fact that Derby's ClientDriver gets automatically loaded at startup by the JDBC infrastructure can easily lead to two versions trying to become active at runtime and causing AbstractMethodError.