# Error while getting Database path in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, derby

I am new to Spring boot and I am writing a code that will fetch me the path to my database when I hit the controller with a request from postman. But with the code I have written it is throwing me an error. The code I wrote was I found on google.
Can I get some help with it ?
Here is my controller code:

```
import org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/createBackup")
public class UserController
{

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @GetMapping("/getPath")
    public void getPath()
    {
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)appContext.getBean("dataSource");
        Connection conn = null;
        DatabaseMetaData dmd = null;
        String url = "";
        try
        {
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            dmd = conn.getMetaData();
            url = url + dmd.getURL();
        }
        catch(SQLException sqe)
        {
            sqe.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(url);
    }
}
```

I use postman to hit this controller and get the path to my database. For now I am printing it out on my console, but this error is bugging me a lot.

The service starts perfectly. but when I hit this controller with a request from Postman, thats when I get this error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.isValid(I)Z
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.checkDriverSupport(PoolBase.java:454) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setupConnection(PoolBase.java:421) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:374) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
...................................and on and on it goes..............................
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a discrepancy between your derby driver implementation and your JDBC API.

A similar question was answered here :
[spring 3, hibernate, dbcp and derby connection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666304/spring-3-hibernate-dbcp-and-derby-connection-issue)

If possible, use the latest version of the derby driver, combined with a recent version of Spring boot.
An example of a simple Rest Controller with Spring boot / derby can be found here :
https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring-boot-apache-derby-example/tree/master/src/main/java/guru/springframework

Note that if you want to get information from the datasource, it's easier to inject the bean:

```
@Autowired
private Datasource ds;
```

than getting it with

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource)appContext.getBean("dataSource");
```